# Reintroduction of Contacts that could be processed by deleting contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder, contact-deletion

This is my question:
For example: I make a backup of number X records on the synchronized Salesforce Account. Then I pause the Synchronize Data Sources and so I start Contact Deletion in the Marketing Cloud from the All Contacts. If, during the Contact Deletion process the data relating to the backup of the X number of records are re-imported into the platform and via CSV in a Data Extension, is it possible to proceed with a one-shot email sending from that DE? Will the imported records have a new ContactKey or could Contact Deletion go wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If after the contact delete process has been run, then you reintroduce that contact in, it will be a brand new contact in the eyes of SFMC with none of the status or tracking history associated with it anymore.